# Finding maximums in mesh of graph?

Tags: computational-geometry, discretization, geometry, calculus

I have a triangle mesh which is an approximation of a smooth graph. i.e. a scalar function of $xy$.

I am interested in finding extrema. One naive way I did it was to look at some number of points around each point (using the mesh graph to locate the neighbours) and test the height. If a point was higher than all its neighbours by at least an epsilon I considered it a maximum.

I am looking for better alternatives.

Comment: How about constructing an interpolation function (does not have to be global interpolation), and testing it for extrema, one triangle at a time?

Comment: If your function is concave, this is a reasonable approach because there is only one maximum. But if it is not concave, then there can be many maxima.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth yes I am trying to find all teh maxima.

Comment: Iterate over all vertices, check if they are highest in their non-marked adjacent cells. If so, mark as local max, mark adjacent cells as done.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your approach is almost there, though the thresholding seems unnecessary. I am assuming within each triangle, you are using linear interpolation to represent your function. Given this, you are looking for all the local maxima and you are given a graph representation $G = (V, E)$ where for any vertex $v \in V$, we assume you can query $v.z$ to grab the $z$ coordinate for the vertex. Given these inputs, it suffices to do the following:

1. On input graph $G$:
2. Initialize an empty array $M$
3. For each vertex $v$ in your graph: append $v$ to $M$ as a local maximum if and only if for all neighbors $u$, $v.z \geq u.z$
4. Return $M$

where we say $u$ is a neighbor of $v$ if there is an edge between $u$ and $v$ in your graph. Let $n := |V|$ and $m := |E|$. If there are $k$ local maximums, the runtime of this algorithm is $O(k)$ for appending the local maximums and the work done to check for local maximums is $O(n + m)$. Since this mesh is going to be a lifted planar graph, we know then that $m \leq 3n$, which implies the overall runtime of the algorithm is $O(k + n)$.

Probably not going to get much better than that without taking into account information about the function your mesh represents. On most cases, you will probably only be able to improve the hidden constants but not the runtime asymptotics.

Like if you knew your function was concave, you should then loop over all vertices to find the vertex $v^*$ with a maximum $z$ coordinate in exactly $n$ time, which would have a smaller runtime constant than the above. If you are worried about multiple vertices having that maximum $z$ coordinate value even in the concave case due to the discretization of your mesh, then just check the neighbors of $v^*$ to see if any of them have the max $z$ value, as that should be enough since your mesh is comprised of triangles. Since generally the degree of $v^*$ should be at most some constant $d$, this means your runtime is only $n + d$ in this case.